# Java Physics loop (repaint on interval) is choppy unless mouse is moving

Tags: java, swing, animation, awt, paint

I have a simple physics loop that does a calculation for a time interval, waits for the interval to pass, and then renders the results on the screen. It's very simple code (even though the timing is probably wrong, but that's exactly what I'm trying to learn about) and works well when I am moving the mouse around the screen.

```
package physicssim;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PhysicsSim extends JFrame {

    private static class PhysicsObject {

        public PhysicsObject(double x, double y, double v_x, double v_y) { 
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.v_x = v_x;
            this.v_y = v_y;
        }

        public double x;
        public double y;
        public double v_x;
        public double v_y;
    }

    PhysicsObject particle;
    boolean running = true;
    DrawPane drawPane;
    public PhysicsSim() {
        particle = new PhysicsObject(10,10, .1, .2);
        drawPane = new DrawPane(particle);
        this.setSize(800,600);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
        this.setContentPane(drawPane);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }


    private static class DrawPane extends JPanel {

        PhysicsObject p;
        public DrawPane(PhysicsObject p) {
            this.p = p;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.           
            g.fillOval((int)p.x, (int) p.y, 10, 10);
        }

    }

    public void start() {
        int FPS = 60;

        long TIME_BETWEEN_FRAMES_NS = 1000000000/FPS;

        // Initial draw
        drawPane.repaint();
        long lastDrawTime = System.nanoTime();

        while(running) {

            // Update physics
            particle.x+=particle.v_x*(TIME_BETWEEN_FRAMES_NS*.0000001);
            particle.y+=particle.v_y*(TIME_BETWEEN_FRAMES_NS*.0000001);

            // While there is time until the next draw wait
            while(TIME_BETWEEN_FRAMES_NS > (System.nanoTime()-lastDrawTime)) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PhysicsSim.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }          

            drawPane.repaint();
            long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println(currentTime - lastDrawTime);
            lastDrawTime = currentTime;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PhysicsSim sim = new PhysicsSim();
        sim.start();

    }

}
```

The last bit about printing the time difference was just a sanity check to make sure that it was in fact calling around the requested interval. The results are fairly consistent so I don't see why there should be any choppiness.

As I mentioned above, this code works great if I a moving the mouse around the screen, everything is smooth.

If I am not moving the mouse it becomes very choppy until I start moving the mouse over the application.

I assume this is something simple, but I hope that you guys can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses.  The "main loop" is woefully inefficient, sleeping for a 1 millisecond is close enough to not sleeping to make no difference.  It would be better to pre-calculate the delay and sleep for at least the amount of time - but that's just me...

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you. I posted the full code. The loop does work, but only when you are moving the mouse on the screen. The reason for not sleeping a set amount of time is that the Thread.sleep(x) isn't always consistent; I will eventually be running very high detail calculations, this is only to work out silly bugs... like this one.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sleeping for 1ms (effectively more) avoids a toaster.. there really isn't need to sleep for longer, although it wouldn't hurt and might get slightly more precise timings.

Comment: @user2864740 As I understand it (and it's limited), `Thread.sleep` is at the mercy of the OS's accuracy and scheduling, which under windows can be between 10-15ms, so it would be effective doing not much at all...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Even if it only slept for 1ms real-world it would still yield execution for a proportionally significant amount of time such that, while not ideal, it is not "woefully inefficient". (The set FPS also yields a ~16ms period so a bigger issue is actually irregular updates - but running through the Swing/repaint stack mostly moots that.)

Comment: @user2864740 But the thread is still consuming CPU cycles in order to be scheduled on and off the run queue, personally, that's still performance hit to take...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sure, sure .. but this extra switching represents an overall insignificant amount of the work done. Now, not having any sleep, *that* would be woefully making toast.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it looks like my problem was I was drawing directly to g in paint(). After replacing with the following everything worked correctly.

```
 @Override
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    img.getGraphics().fillOval((int) p.x, (int) p.y, 10, 10);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
  }
```

I was considering deleting this code snippet because it's rough and shameful, but maybe it will help someone else. Happy coding.

Comment: Well if it's a buffering issue, use `paintComponent` instead of `paint` as it will be within the components double buffering capacity.  Also, you really should be using `getWidth` and `getHeight` instead of magic numbers